# Google+ check-in location in ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, geolocation, google-plus

I want to implement location check-in feature in ios. My application is using google+ ios sdk. The problem which I am facing is that after I have implemented google+ check-in feature then that post is not being displayed on my google+ account.

The technique which I have tried and implemented is written below.

```
  -(IBAction)checkIn
  {
   GTMOAuth2Authentication *auth = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].authentication;

   GTLServicePlus* plusService = [[GTLServicePlus alloc] init] ;
   plusService.retryEnabled = YES;
    [plusService setAuthorizer:auth];

GTLPlusMoment *moment = [[GTLPlusMoment alloc] init];
moment.type =  @"http://schemas.google.com/CheckInActivity";
GTLPlusItemScope *target = [[GTLPlusItemScope alloc] init] ;
target.url =@"https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/snippet/examples/place";

moment.target = target;

 GTLQueryPlus *query =
[GTLQueryPlus queryForMomentsInsertWithObject:moment
                                       userId:@"me"
                                  collection:kGTLPlusCollectionVault];

[plusService executeQuery:query
        completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                            id object,
                            NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                GTMLoggerError(@"Error: %@", error);
                NSString *failure =
                [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Status: Error: %@", error];
                NSLog(@"%@",failure);

            } else {
               NSString *result = @"CheckedIn Saved in Google+";
                NSLog(@"%@",result);
            }
        }];

        }
```

Can any one please help me out. Is this the right way of implementing location check-in feature of google+ or is there any other method for it?

Comment: I want to post my current location check-in on my google+ wall not in the app activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you're using is writing an "app activity" to Google+, which stores a "moment" in the user's app activity vault. As noted on https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/app-activities these moments are not directly visible on the user's stream, although users may choose to share them to the stream if they wish.

To see the moments that have been shared, you will need to use the desktop app. Your profile has a list of apps that are using the Google+ Sign-In and you can view, share, and delete the activities for each of these apps. The mobile Google+ clients don't let you view the activities yet.

Comment: ok I got it and I have seen on my profile that it is actually showing the activities on the app section in my google+ account. Actually I want to implement location share check-in feature, means that a user can share his current location through my app and post it on his wall. Can you tell me how is that possible way to implement that?

Comment: Take a look at https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share for more about how and what you can share. But, in general, Google+ intentionally does not allow apps to directly post to a user's wall without them taking a specific action - the App Activity gives the user the opportunity to take that specific action.